# Xamarin 'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'Tabbar' error

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, android-sdk-manager

I've created a basic `xamarin.forms` project (with PCL code sharing strategy) and I'm getting error for the following two lines in `MainActivity::OnCreate()`

```
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

> CS0117    'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'Tabbar'
>   CS0117  'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'Toolbar'

The resource files exist as `Resources\layout\Tabbar.axml` and `Resources\layout\Toolbar.axml` and the build action for both of them is set to `AndroidResource`.

I suspect there is something wrong with my android SDK installation. Currently the following packages are installed:

[image]

But the `Run` button in Visual Studio 2015 still is showing `Android 6.0 API 23` and it's not possible to change it:

[image]

I've also set the `Target Framework` version of the Android project to 7.1:

[image]

The project structure is as the following:

[image]

I've followed [this tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) step by step to create the sample project.

How can I get the error fixed?

Comment: can you provide the sample project ? That will tell us if the problem is your project or environment

Comment: @YuriS Updated the question with a snapshot of project structure and a link to the tutorial source code. Note that even a starter `xamarin.forms` template project gives this error and it's not related to the tutorial I've followed.

Comment: do you want me to take a look on your machine using teamviewer?

Comment: @YuriS Unfortunately that's not an option

Comment: no problem. check your environment then.

Comment: @YuriS Any suggestion what should I check first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150497/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-meysam).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems in API installed. It is still a little mystery for me which APIs must be installed but deleting the build tools 24 and installing build tools 26.0.1 fixed the issue for build.

Then installed NDK which was missing and set path in Xamarin options. 
Now 2 options are available for computers supporting HAXM and/or Hyper-V

1. HAXM. Disable Hyper-V. Then change emulator setting in AVD manager which were not created and download an Itom image for emulator using Android SDK. Download and install HAXM. You are ready.
2. Enable Hyper-V. Download and install Hyper-V VS emulators. Run it and create emulator(s) virtual machine(s). You are ready.

Run your app.

Comment: Did not help for me. Running Visual Studio Mac 2017.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I included two files into "**layout**" folder: **Tabbar.axml** and **Toolbar.axml**. Following the Xamarin documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/appcompat-material-design

I solved the problem just right clicking in those files, selecting Properties and changing the **Build Action** to **AndroidResource**.

Comment: When you include a file in layout folder, VS adds the xml extension and the Build Action is AndroidResource. If you change the extension to axml, the Build Action is changed to Content. That´s the problem!