# SetContentView(Resource.Layout.V2T) CS0117 Error 'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'V2T'

Tags: c#, setcontentview

Using Visual Studio to develop a Xamarin cross platform APP.  I have specific Android code I have added to the Android specific build.  I get the CS0117 error when trying to compile.  I have a 'V2T.axml' file in the Resources/layout folder.    The line in the CS code with the error is:

SetContentView(Resource.Layout.V2T);

Any idea what is wrong?

Also get 2 more CS0117 errors for problems with 'Resource.Id" does not contain definition errors - but I have defined those two resources.

Any ideas?

CS:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // set the isRecording flag to false (not recording)
        isRecording = false;

        // Set our view to: V2T.axml
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.V2T);

        // get the resources from the layout
        recButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRecord);
        textBox = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textYourText);
```

V2T.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="3">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:text="Start Recording"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnRecord" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:text="Your text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textYourText"
        android:textColor="#ffedf01d"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: consider post more code

Comment: Here is code snippet: CS:               protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // set the isRecording flag to false (not recording)
            isRecording = false;

            // Set our view to: V2T.axml
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.V2T);

            // get the resources from the layout
            recButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRecord);
            textBox = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textYourText);

Comment: what is wrong in this line `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.V2T);` ?

Comment: Not sure - I have used this exact code in a standalone APP and it worked.  What am I missing?

Comment: please post the errors

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0117 'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'V2T' EnSpect.Android D:\Other\Software\Xamarin\EnSpect\EnSpect\EnSpect.Android\Voice2Text.cs 28 Active

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0117 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'btnRecord' EnSpect.Android D:\Other\Software\Xamarin\EnSpect\EnSpect\EnSpect.Android\Voice2Text.cs 31 Active

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0117 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'textYourText' EnSpect.Android D:\Other\Software\Xamarin\EnSpect\EnSpect\EnSpect.Android\Voice2Text.cs 32 Active

Comment: have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393794/xamarin-resource-layout-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-tabbar-error ?

Comment: I will go read that now. Will check back in a few

Comment: Still have the same problem.  I updated to latest API, SDK & removed old versions.  HOWEVER, I was not able to install the NDK - it kept failing.  Do I need that?  I found the NDK download site & currently downloading the latest

Comment: I downloaded NDK, but not sure how to have Visual Studio install it.  Do I need this?   As mentioned above, I have a standalone APP that works with this code.  Just when I added it to my large APP project is when I get these errors.

Comment: I no idea about this..sorry

Answer (score 0):

Clean Solution and rebuild, The layout xml wasn't built successfully That should solve it

Comment: When editing the CS code, the IntelliSense editor does not know about the 'V2T.axml' resource.  As mentioned above, I copied files from a standalone CS project and put them into a larger Xamarin Forms projects with Android, iOS & Windows projects.  I put everything into the Android project files.  Do I need to specify the name space or project files when using the 'Resource.Layout.V2T' statement?   How does that statement know to go look into my "EnSpect.Android" /Resources/layout folder to find V2T.axml?

Comment: IntelliSense does not see any files in 'Resource/Layout'.  What am I missing?  I have 'Tabbar.axml' & 'Toolbar.axml' also in that folder - but IntelliSense does not see them.

Comment: It is FIXED!  I corrected my namespace in my CS file, from "EnSpect" to "EnSpect.Droid".  Thanks to all who helped!